Qodana complains about "Uri is not registered" from a XML file but not in Rider
I have a XML file in my C# project and added it in Rider to Settings->Languages & Frameworks->Schemas and DTDs and have no issues so far, but when the server side analysis runs over the code he is complaining about URI is not registered.
Schema: http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
Does anyone know how to solve that in Qodana?
